# Homology of linear groups over integral domains and their field of fractions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, group-homology

Let $A$ be a noetherian integral domain of finite Krull dimension with the field of fractions of $F$. Consider the natural injections $i_n:GL_n(A)\hookrightarrow GL_{n+1}(A)$, $j_n:GL_n(F)\hookrightarrow GL_{n+1}(F)$, $\varphi_n:GL_n(A)\hookrightarrow GL_n(F)$ and similarly $\varphi_{n+1}$. Let $x\in H_k(BGL_{n+1}(A))$ and assume that $\varphi_{*(n+1)}(x)$ lies in the image of $j_{*n}$ i.e. for some $y\in H_k(BGL_n(F))$, $j_{*n}(y)=\varphi_{*(n+1)}(x)$. Does that imply that $y$ is in the image of  $\varphi_{*n}$?